# DataTables.net Width not working with Sort

Tags: jquery, css, razor, asp.net-core, datatables-1.10

I am using DataTables.net to populate a table, however, I cannot get the Width option to work. I have tried several of DataTables options to do so all without any luck, so I created a CSS function to manually control the width and that works.

However for my CSS function to apply I need to add a class on that `<td>` with a `<div>` which requires me to do a `render: function()`.

Once I do that now my sorting does not work. So I need to either find a way to have DataTable set my width correctly, or have it sort with the data in a `<div>`

Here is my table:

```
mobileTable = $('#MobileTable #mobileTransaction').DataTable({
            data: mobileData,
            cache: false,
            retrieve: true,
            order: [0, "desc"],
            lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100],
            columnDefs: [
                { type: 'date', targets: 0 },
                //{ width: "1%", targets: 0 }
            ],
            columns: [
                {
                    data: null,
                    title: 'Date',
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<div class="text-wrap width-date">' + full.settledate + '</div>'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    title: "Description",
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<div class="text-wrap width-narr">' + full.narratives + '</div>'
                    }
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<td><div id="ExpandTransaction" data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-warning btn-anim btn-square width-exp"><i></i><span class="btn-text fa fa-search-plus pt-10"></span></div></td>'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

and the CSS

```
.text-wrap {
        white-space: normal;
    }

    .width-narr {
        width: 150px;
    }

    .width-date {
        width: 50px;
    }
```

Additionally if there is a way to set the overall table width to fit your screen size that would be ideal since that's basically what I am doing by manually setting column widths.

TL;DR How set column width while still allowing to sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the style as a columnDef instead of a seperate CSS function did the trick:

```
mobileTable = $('#MobileTable #mobileTransaction').DataTable({
            data: mobileData,
            cache: false,
            retrieve: true,
            order: [0, "desc"],
            lengthMenu: [25, 50, 75, 100],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                        $(td).css('max-width', '50px')
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 1,
                    "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                        $(td).css('max-width', '150px')
                        $(td).css('white-space', 'normal')
                    }
                },
                { type: 'date', targets: 0 }
            ],
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'settleDate',
                    title: 'Date'
                },
                {
                    data: 'narratives',
                    title: "Description"
                },
                {
                    data: null,
                    orderable: false,
                    render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<div id="ExpandTransaction" data-id="' + full.id + '" class="btn btn-warning btn-anim btn-square width-exp"><i></i><span class="btn-text fa fa-search-plus pt-10"></span></div>'
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```